# AssersionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I want to run this [repo](https://github.com/jimmy646/violin). I installed everything that is needed for this project.

I have Windows 8.1 operating system, seems that I don't have NVIDIA GPU (from Device Manager: Display adapters - AMD Radeon HD 7660G + 7670M Dual Graphics and AMD Radeon HD 7670M).

I installed torch with command that is presented on [Pytorch web-site](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

```
pip install torch==1.6.0+cpu torchvision==0.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

But when I run the project I receive error - **AssersionError: Tourch not compiled with CUDA enabled**.

Then I tried to install torch with CUDA enabled.

```
pip install torch===1.6.0 torchvision===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

But when I run the project I receive error - **AssersionError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx**.

Please, help me to solve my issue and run the project without errors.

Comment: if you dont have GPU, you should try to use google colab for this project.

Answer (score 3):

I have already fixed this issue. There was a problem in source code where they use

```
opt.device
```

in main.py and violin_dataset.py. But this was declared as

```
opt.device = torch.device('cuda:0')
```

in config.py even if you didn't have cuda support.
So I changed it to

```
opt.device = torch.device('cpu')
```

And everything works fine now.